# Como acceder a las funciones/propiedades de un archivo .so en python

Tags: python, funciones

Tengo un archivo .so y he dejado de lado el hecho de descompilar el archivo por toda la dificultad que conlleva y mejor me gustaria ver si hay alguna manera de acceder a las propiedades, funciones de este archivo .so y lograr verl@s

Así es como creo mi instancia llamada "l" y le cargo la libreria con extensión .so

[image: Asi cargo la libreria en python]

he intentado que por ejemplo en Visual Studio Code cuando uno crea una instancia de algo al momento de colocar un "." en la instancia se muestran las propiedades/funciones que contiene esa instancia.

[image: Propiedades]

Entonces busco lograr algo asi..pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo..¿Alguien sabrá comó?

Comment: De la misma manera que no puedes descompilarlo, no hay una forma directa de obtener los nombres a partir de un archivo binario. Tienes que recurrir a la documentación para saber qué funciones brinda y su declaración. De qué librería se trata y qué sistema operativo estás usando?

Comment: Es una libreria que me dieron pero no tengo la documentación de la misma, lo unico que tengo es el archivo .so y ya. Es por eso que estoy optando por ver la menera de acceder a su contenido.

Comment: Estoy utilizando Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar algún programa como [Detect It Easy](https://github.com/horsicq/Detect-It-Easy) para ver los nombres de las funciones que exporta. Lo bueno de este es que funciona con muchos formatos de archivos binarios y se encuentra disponible para Windows, Linux y Mac.

En el caso de un DLL, toca **Export**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y puedes ver las funciones a la derecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Para un .so tocas **ELF**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y seleccionas **Symbol table**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los nombres de las funciones también aparecen a la derecha.

---

Según las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2891493):

También puedes usar `dumpbin` del símbolo de sistema para desarrollador de Visual Studio (para **.dll**).

```
dumpbin -exports archivo.dll
```

O `nm` en Linux (para **.so**).

```
nm -D archivo.so
```

Comment: Un comentario extra para quien vea esta publicación es que si estas en Linux y ejecutas ```nm -DC archivo.so``` te devuelve las funciones/atributos que tiene la libreria y ademas si las funciones necesitan parametros o no.